# Duvida cast de ponteiro

Tags: c

Galera quando se tem uma linha tipo esta:

```
u_char variavel_teste
struct teste *p ; 
p = (struct  teste *)variavel_teste;
```

Qual a utilidade disto , e o que significa , podem me dar um exemplo de programa?

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = '5';
```

Um char tem o tamanho de 1 byte e seu endereço é `0x12345678`.

```
char *d = &c;
```

Você obtém o endereço de `c` e guarda em `d` e `d` passa a valer `0x12345678`.

```
int *e = (int*)d;
```

Você esta fazendo com que seu compilador entenda que `0x12345678` aponta para um `int` (inteiro), entretanto, um `int` não é do tamanho de 1 byte `(sizeof(char) != sizeof(int))`, é 4 bytes ou 8 de acordo com a arquitetura.

Assim quando se exibe o valor do ponteiro de tipo inteiro é considerado o primeiro byte que estava em `c` e os outros bytes consecutivos que estão na pilha (stack) é considerado lixo para o seu inteiro.

Considerando esta situação não é vantagem fazer cast de ponteiro com tipos diferentes.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260527/what-are-the-rules-for-casting-pointers-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

```
u_char variavel_teste
struct teste *p ;
p = (struct teste *)variavel_teste;
```

A ultima linha tem erro e o compilador tem de se queixar (com erro ou warning).

O que essa expressao faz é pegar no valor de tipo `u_char` contido na variavel `variavel_teste`, converter esse valor para o valor correspondente do tipo `struct teste *` e atribuir o resultado da conversao a variavel `p`. Mas nao ha correspondencia entre estes dois tipos de valores e portanto esta conversao é invalida e o compilador tem de se queixar.

Nota que o *cast* (a conversao explicita) nao é estritamente necessaria pois o compilador é forcado a fazer a conversao automaticamente em atribuicoes de tipos compativeis.

Sugestao: liga o maximo de warnings do teu compilador e tenta fazer sempre compilacoes limpas.

Comment: pmg mais variavel_teste vira uma struct do tipo teste?

Comment: Nao. o valor de `variavel_teste` é convertido (seria, se fosse possivel) num ponteiro para um objecto de tipo `struct teste`.